# how to get the absolute values in each element of array

Tags: c#, arrays, min, absolute-value

I have some problem in converting the elements in the array to absolute values.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nQ = {0}, difference = |{1} - {2}| = {3} ",
                  a + 1, store[a], store2[a], Math.Abs(store3[a]));
```

the store3 is a array. I already inputted it some elements in my program.
and I will get the right answer
and the problem is after getting the absolute value I have to find the minimum value of the array but it returns the negative integer. and i want only to return the smallest or minimum of the elements in their absolute value. How will I do this. I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want "smallest or minimum of the elements in their absolute value", try direct `Min` with required lambda:

```
store3.Min(x => Math.Abs(x));
```

Implementation

```
Console.WriteLine("\nQ = {0}, difference = |{1} - {2}| = {3} ",
                  a + 1, 
                  store[a], 
                  store2[a], 
                  store3.Min(x => Math.Abs(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to get the Abs value

```
store3Abs = store3.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).ToArray();
```

If you don't need the intermediate abs array, you can just get the minimum directly

```
var min = store3.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).Min();
```

Comment: how will I display the minimum in console?

Comment: but it only returns 0

Comment: What are the values of store3? 0 would be the minimum if store3 has 0. Writing to console is with the Console.WriteLine method